# SSIS ForEach loop through multplie excel files

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to parse through multiple excel files using Foreach Loop Container and getting the error blow.  Whats annoying me is the for each loop works when the "Excel File Path" is set to 1 file in excel connection manager. But it loops through the same file multiple times.  However, I need to loop through each file once and move to the next file. so I need to add an expression to excel connection manager. And its when I add an expression of the variable is when the error occurs

### TITLE: Package Validation Error

Package Validation Error

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

Error at Package [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager 1"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid argument.".

(Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 0):

I had to set delay validation on the excel connection manager and everything else to get this to run OK

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.

Comment: I think he's saying that setting delay validation to true was the answer.  I was about to suggest it.

Comment: Please click the check mark to show that this is the answer and close the question.